# open file directory

Tags: delphi, oracle10g

hi to all 
I insert into Oracle database image file on Delphi(create table (id int,dir varchar2(200),image blob). Now I want to open  directory(dir) of that file on dblick dbimage1
example: D:\image.bmp
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to open a Shell window at "D:\" ? Are you to extract the file path from `D:\image.bmp`?

Comment: I want when I double click on dbimage1 to open than file with Windows Fax and Picture Viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uses ShellAPI;

...

// opens Windows Explorer with the file highlighted
ShellExecute(Handle,
             'open',
             'C:\Windows\explorer.exe',
             '/start,"' + ImageFileName + '"',
             nil,
             SW_SHOWNORMAL);

// opens the default program associated with the type (extension) of the file,
// which in your case can very well be Windows Fax and Picture Viewer
ShellExecute(Handle,
             'open',
             nil,
             '"' + ImageFileName + '"',
             nil,
             SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

If `ImageFileName` already contains `"`, remove them in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to change this shellapi code ShellExecute (Handle,'C:\Windows\explorer.exe','/start,"'+mydirectiory+  '"',  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL); like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TOpenPictureDialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtDlgs.TOpenPictureDialog) to let the user select an image file.

Comment: I think the OP is struggling with english, but wants to open a file that they already know the filename and path for, thus, there is no need to browse for it.

Comment: @Warren P Yes most likely but this question suggests that he actually used the TOpenPictureDialog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308661/insert-jpeg-files-to-oracle